# Should ALL divs float left?

Tags: css

I'm designing within an application that I inherited.  I have done a lot of work to "consolidate" the CSS which was extremely overworked through much copying and pasting without a lot of strategy behind it.  One curious thing I found was to style ALL divs as:

```
<style>
div{ float: left; }
</style>
```

Do any other applications do this?  I would be "unfloating" divs all the time because the majority of my use of divs is in fact a division of content, forcing a new line for items like cell phones and tablets.  In my practices, I will style a div float-left if I specifically need it to do that.

Comment: Any chance this is part of a fluid layout?

Comment: No, not all. Arabic and Hebrew ones should float right.

Answer (score 2):

Element-based selectors such as `a`, `img` or `div` are mostly used for two purposes:

1. To clean up browser inconsistencies.

   For example, `h1 { font-size: 3em; }` will remove inconsistencies in default size between different browsers and versions of browsers.
2. To set the default behavior instead of a specific behavior.

   For example, `img { border: none; }` ensures that Internet Explorer will not display blue border around images when they are embedded in a link. If, on a page, there are a few images where I *want* to display a border and a few dozen of images where I don't, it's easier to `img { border: none; }`, then to set a border on those images where I want a border.

In most websites, elements are positioned according to the browser defaults, and are `float: left` only when needed. For those websites, `div { float: left; }` wouldn't make sense: it doesn't remove any browser inconsistencies and it sets the specific behavior, rather than the default one.

On the other hand, some very specific websites may prefer `float: left` to be the default. [svidgen](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246834/should-all-divs-float-left#comment495683_246834) suggested fluid layouts. I think more about games. For example, I'm currently working on a game and nearly every element is `position: absolute`, so `#map div { position: absolute; }` makes sense.

To determine whether you should keep the `div { float: left; }`, study:

- How many `div`s are actually `float: left;` on the page,
- How many are not,
- Where `float: left;` effect is cancelled, and how painful is that.

  You may as well find that the effect is cancelled nearly in every class. I had that several times when maintaining legacy applications, encountering some weird styles such as `div { font-size: 13px !important; }`.